# PHP - Using XML for a config file(s) are elements better than attributes or opposite?

Tags: php, xml, standards, config

I'm using XML for a config file in PHP (Using SimpleXML), in creating the config file what is more of a standard.

Having all values in elements or using the attributes?

Elements Example:

```
<database>
   <user>test-user</user>
   <pass>test-pass</pass>
</database>
```

Attribute Example:

```
<database user="test-user" pass="test-pass"></database>
```

Are there any benefits of either way?

Also other languages might need to read the same config file, such as Java and Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The oldest question asked by adopters
>   of XML is when to use elements and
>   when to use attributes in XML design.
>   As with most design issues, this
>   question rarely has absolute answers,
>   but developers have also experienced a
>   lack of very clear guidelines to help
>   them make this decision.

See [Principles of XML design: When to use elements versus attributes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleatt.html) by IBM. Pretty nice article.

Here's a snippet:

In my experience working with users of XML, the first question is by far the most common. In some cases the answer is pretty unambiguous:

- If the information in question could be itself marked up with elements, put it in an element.
- If the information is suitable for attribute form, but could end up as multiple attributes of the same name on the same element, use child elements instead.
- If the information is required to be in a standard DTD-like attribute type such as ID, IDREF, or ENTITY, use an attribute.
- If the information should not be normalized for white space, use elements. (XML processors normalize attributes in ways that can change the raw text of the attribute value.)

Comment: The article looks great and many thanks. It was written in 2004 but it looks to still hold some key points.

Answer (score -2):

XML was invented to be a human-readable format, but it's so formalized that no one dares to edit it manually or even read it.

As no one would read it, I'd suggest to use PHP itself.

```
<?
    $config['db']['user']="user";
    $config['db']['pass']="pass";
?>
```

It's slightly more secure and reliable.

Comment: I would like to keep it PHP as well but currently that would involve a deployment window as it would be defined as a code change. Using XML would be a config change that could be made on the fly. So no deployment window :)

Comment: Somehow, I fail to see how editing a file that contains PHP code that is executed would be more secure or more reliable than using a XML file. You can't sneak a @``$_GET[z]`` into an XML file...

Comment: I agree with this. You can also have a php file with a pile of DEFINES in. If you are using php I see no reason to use xml as xml is actually slower than a php file.